# Mail properties not being saved in UpdateAsync

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am starting out in MS Graph. I have below code to pick up all mail messages from Inbox of a specific user. Then I go through each message, process it and set its Subject. When I try to save back message using UpdateAsync it executes fine but change in mail subject text doesn't seem to get saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Regards

```
   var inboxMessages = await graphClient
       .Users[user.Id]
       .MailFolders.Inbox
       .Messages
       .Request()
       .OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC")
       .GetAsync();
    
     foreach(Microsoft.Graph.Message x in inboxMessages) {
    
       //Process message
    
       // ...
    
       x.Subject = "Processed: " + x.Subject
    
       //Save changes to message Subject
       await graphClient
         .Users[user.Id]
         .MailFolders.Inbox
         .Messages[$"{x.Id}"]
         .Request()
         .UpdateAsync(x);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) you can update `Subject` only for messages that have `isDraft = true` but not for those that have already been sent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a shame. I used to be able to do this with EWS so assumed would work in MS Graph too. These are incoming emails though.

Comment: This seems to have done the job.

            var subject = originalmessage.Subject;

                    originalmessage.IsDraft = true;

                    graphClient
                        .Users[user.Id]
                        .MailFolders.Inbox
                        .Messages[$"{originalmessage.Id}"]
                        .Request()
                        .UpdateAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.Message()
                        {
                            Subject = subject
                        });

                    originalmessage.IsDraft = false;